# Why are commands missing from this yargs script help page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, yargs

Can someone explain why the below script doesn't show the help for all commands?

```
test.js [command]

Commands:
  test.js list-spaces  List spaces

Options:
  --help     Show help                                                 [boolean]
  --version  Show version number                                       [boolean]
```

Notice the help for `list-commands` is missing for some reason.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict'
const yargs = require("yargs");

yargs.command({
  command: 'list-spaces',
  describe: 'List spaces',
  type: 'boolean',
  handler: function(argv) {
    console.log('aaa');
  }
}).argv;

yargs.command({
  command: 'list-connectors',
  describe: 'List connectors',
  builder: {
    space: {
      describe: 'space',
      demandOption: true,
      type: 'string'
    },
  },
  handler: function(argv) {
    console.log(argv.space);
  }
}).argv;
```

Comment: You mean `list-connectors`, not `list-commands`?

Comment: You can chain the commands like this: `yargs.command().command().command().help().argv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing `.argv` is what triggers the parsing (of `process.args`) and output generation. From [the docs](https://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference):

> Calling `.parse()` with no arguments is equivalent to calling `.argv`
>
> […]
>
> The rest of these methods below come in just **before** the **terminating** `.argv` or terminating `.parse()`.

You're accessing `.argv` twice for some reason. The first time, the second command is not yet registered. The second statement doesn't even run any more.